# Derivative of measures

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, derivatives

I think most upper level analysis books (including Rudin) decide to "reintroduce" the idea of a derivative by transitioning from measure theory to the idea of differentiating measures.

I get that this theory has power because it extends to a lot more than "differentiable functions" as we learn in high school, but specifically **what are the advantages of this concept** of differentiating measures (as opposed to functions)?

Also, one extra minor question. What's the quickest way to recover the standard
$$lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ definition of a limit from the derivative of measures lingo?

Comment: There is a fairly strong connection for (Lebesgue) integrable functions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem. Think of it as a generalisation of the fundamental theorem of calculus.